# activity to fragment to activity and then back to fragment

Tags: android

Activity - { FragmentA , FragmentB, FragmentC }
FragmentC - NewActivity (Backpress) - FragmentC

I want to go back from the NewActivtiy to the FragmentC what I called. How can I write for this.

Answer (score 0):

In NewActivity (onBackPressed) call finish()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
finish();
}
```

Comment: I did this. But, not Ok.